# Unable to work out Update Panel Async property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

My problem is i have encapsulated a set of controls in Update Panel. for the first time when page runs my **Mutual()** method gets called. When i click on Button1_click, the current value of **row[i]** stores in database, but when i click on Button2 for incrementing the ith value of row[i] and call Mutual(i) , it doesn't get called...

Please tell me where am i wrong or i am missing something? Why is this happening?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
           //Access values from database and store into DataRow[] row
           i=0;
           ViewState["i"] = i;
           Mutual(i);
         }

     }
 protected void Mutual(int i)
 {
    //display row[i] 

 }
 protected void Button1_click(...)
  {

    //store current row[i] value into database
  }

 protected void Button2_click(....)
 {
   i = (int)ViewState["i"];
   i++;
   ViewState["i"] = i;
   Mutual(i);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

it better if you show aspx code.....That a typical problem you get when placing the controls inside an update panel here are couple of solutions

1)  you may use triggers to trigger the server side event by placing triggers inside your update panel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
<Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="Click" />
 </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

2) using jquery ajax function to call your method. /// but that if nothing else works